# Generating an SHA1 hash under Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Environment:

```
Ruby 1.9.3.p125
Ubuntu 14.04
```

I tried:

```
1.9.3p125 :011 > require 'digest/sha1'
 => false
1.9.3p125 :012 >
```

I also tried 'digest' with the same results. I would like to generate an SHA1 hash, but I can't do it because I cannot load the required module. My research on Stackoverflow and Google tell me that I am using the proper syntax. The Ruby language docs tell me the same thing as well.

Does anyone know of some other method to generate SHA1 hashes under Ruby?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What is the *precise* error message you are getting? What does "I cannot load the required module" mean? Note that you don't `require` modules in Ruby, you `require` *files*. The code you have looks perfectly fine to me, but you will obviously have to use the code you loaded, not just load it and sit there and wait for it to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` does not mean a failure to require the specified file... it simply means that the file has already been required successfully, and is available.

This should be what happens when you try the command:

```
crypto_hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("hello")
=> "aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d"
```

Comment: Thank you. That saved me a lot of time